# How to line through all links of a certain div id and bold mark specific paragraph without affecting others

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, text-styling

This is the [end-product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAKkF.jpg) i'm supposed to make and i'm at [this-stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U4pA.jpg).

How do i line-through in css all porttitor>/a> that is in 
 without affecting .

And how do i bold mark the last paragraph of both borders as shown in the end-product without bold marking everything?
Also if you want you can tell me if i shouldve written everything in a different way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Uppgift 4E</title>
    <style>
      html {
        background-color: lightslategrey;
      }

      body {
        margin: auto;
        width: 500px;
        padding-bottom: 0.1px;
        /*knep för div margin */
        background-color: #f0ffff;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;

      }

      h1 {
        Color: purple;
      }

      #billy {
        color: darkred;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: purple;
        border-width: 1.5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 10px;
      }

      #bob {
        color: darkgreen;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: purple;
        border-width: 1.5px;
        /* border tjockhet */
        border-radius: 5px;
        /* rundiga kanter på border */
        text-align: left;
        margin: 10px;
      }

      p {
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
      }

      .two {
        font-size: large;
      }

      .three {
        font-size: small;
      }

      #bob>.two>a {
        text-decoration: overline underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Uppgift 4E</h1>
    <div id="billy">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Suspendisse imperdiet velit sit amet neque tempor et imperdiet augue <a href="">porttitor</a>.
      </p>
      <p class="two">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Suspendisse imperdiet velit sit amet neque tempor et imperdiet augue <a href="">porttitor</a>.
      </p>
      <p class="three">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Suspendisse imperdiet velit sit amet neque tempor et imperdiet augue <a href="">porttitor</a>.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Suspendisse imperdiet velit sit amet neque tempor et imperdiet augue <a href="">porttitor</a>.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="bob">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Suspendisse imperdiet velit sit amet neque tempor et imperdiet augue <a href="">porttitor</a>.
      </p>
      <p class="two">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Suspendisse imperdiet velit sit amet neque tempor et imperdiet augue <a href="">porttitor</a>.
      </p>
      <p class="three">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Suspendisse imperdiet velit sit amet neque tempor et imperdiet augue <a href="">porttitor</a>.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Suspendisse imperdiet velit sit amet neque tempor et imperdiet augue <a href="">porttitor</a>.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The second sentence seems to be messed up.  "porttitor"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<s></s>` (strike-through) tag or `<del>` . The `<strike>` tag is obsolete is HTML5.

example:

```css
.two a {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Rachel</p>
<!--Rachel in paragraph tags-->

<p><s>Rachel</s></p>
<!--Rachel in paragraph tags with inner 's' tags-->

<p class="two">I my name is <a href ="#">Rachel</a></p>
<!--line-through css-->
```

You can also use css

```
 .yourclass a{text-decoration: line-through;}
```

Regarding bolding text, use `font-weight:bold;`

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not supposed to change the HTML code, only the css code

Comment: @Thankyouforhelping that wasn't clear. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Thankyouforhelping by adding the 'a' after the class in the css, you target the href, so it doesn't affect the entire paragraph

Comment: @Thankyouforhelping I'd be grateful if you could you accept my answer?  (hover to the left of answer and click the tick to accept)

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a class to an HTML element, then you could make a class specifically for bold or line-through, then apply it to what paragraphs that you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text-decoration: line-through;` style.  It's not obvious what your criterion is for what to affect with this, so I can't suggest a selector.

To mark the last paragraph of each div:

```
div>p:nth-last-of-type(1) { font-weight: bold; font-size: 110%; }
```

And you might find fitting the parts together a little easier if you always use:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

so that container sizes will actually be what a reasonable person would expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#bob p:last-child {
   font-weight:bold;
}
#bob p:not(.two) a {
   text-decoration:line-through;
}
```